# Conditional operators in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Can we use conditional operators in objective C as like in the C++. I just tried to implement like this
(condition) ? true-statement : false-statement;

```
 if(page==1)?(buttonPrev.hidden=TRUE):(buttonPrev.hidden=FALSE);
```

But it results an error "Expected expression"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes you can use. try like this and don't keep if statement for checking the condition that is the problem in your case.

```
 (page==1)?(buttonPrev.hidden=TRUE):(buttonPrev.hidden=FALSE);
```

if you want to assign the value directly then simply use

```
buttonPrev.hidden=(page==1)?TRUE:FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
buttonPrev.hidden = (page==1)?TRUE:FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you Understand the Concept of `"Conditional operators"` ?

**Syntax :** `(Condition) ? (Response for TRUE) : (Response For FALSE) ;`

Removing `IF` is the Answer of your Question.

Answer (score 1):

```
buttonPrev.hidden = (page==1) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```